# Kubuntu mismatch in ips

Tags: kubuntu

I just installed dualboot Kubuntu and Windows and when I boot my new Kubuntu I see this error:
[ERROR miscmatch in ips_enabled.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6e8n3.jpg) PC works, and I can use Kubuntu, but I think it is problem.

OUTPUT  of command lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 380d
    Kernel driver in use: i915


03:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 840M] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 380d
```

(Sorry for my english.)
Thanks guys